# can't connect to the server, TCP socket android

Tags: android

I am trying to open up a TCP socket in my client application so that it can talk to my server.
after going through the documentation, i am curious about the socket constructor, which takes two parameters.

```
Socket(InetAddress dstAddress, int dstPort)
Creates a new streaming socket connected to the target host specified by the parameters dstAddress and dstPort.
```

and its description is as above. So as I learned, after creating the socket, I should have explicitly called the connect function in order for it to connect to the server. But in some TCP client sample codes I found online, none of them actually calls the connect function

```
connect(SocketAddress remoteAddr, int timeout)
```

So I am thinking if the constructor automatically connects to the server after being created? the three-ways handshake is done. or I have to explicitly call the connect function after the constructor?  Thank you so much

Comment: yea, it turns out the constructor takes care of the connecting part.Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only the two constructors that don't take any kind of target **do not connect**:

- `Socket()`
  Creates a new **unconnected** socket.
- `Socket(Proxy)`
  Creates a new **unconnected** socket using the given proxy type.

All the other constructors where you pass the target as hostname or address **do connect**:

- `Socket(String, int)`
  Creates a new streaming socket **connected** to the target host specified by the parameters dstName and dstPort.
- `Socket(String, int, InetAddress, int)` Creates a new streaming socket **connected** to the target host specified by the parameters dstName and dstPort.
- `Socket(InetAddress, int)`
  Creates a new streaming socket **connected** to the target host specified by the parameters dstAddress and dstPort.
- `Socket(InetAddress, int, InetAddress, int)`
  Creates a new streaming socket **connected** to the target host specified by the parameters dstAddress and dstPort.

I left out the two deprecated constructors.

This is straight from the [Android API documentation for `java.lang.Socket`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/Socket.html#pubctors).

Comment: Thank you, it explains everything

Answer (score 0):

Socket constructors work according with the documentation, some make also connection, other not.
Please see: 
http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/Socket.html

Handshake is automatically done, you don't need to take care of it.

Comment: Thank you, it explains everything